# Segmentation Fault when testing Sequel Model with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, sequel

I just do this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Donor' do
  it "does something" do
    d = Donor.new
    d.name = 'ABC'
  end
end
```

And it fails miserably:

```
$> bundle exec rspec spec/tombamento/donor_spec.rb 2>&1 | head
/home/nerde/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.10.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:2094: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000018
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0020 p:0129 s:0090 e:000089 METHOD /home/nerde/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.10.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:2094
c:0019 p:0011 s:0084 e:000083 METHOD /home/nerde/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.10.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1171
c:0018 p:0014 s:0076 e:000074 METHOD /home/nerde/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.10.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:850
c:0017 p:0026 s:0071 e:000069 BLOCK  /media/shared/home/git/unila/tombamento/spec/tombamento/donor_spec.rb:6 [FINISH]
...
```

I found the line in the Sequel gem where the trace points:

```
begin
  model.db.typecast_value(col_schema[:type], value)
rescue InvalidValue
```

The problem occurs when calling the `model` method. I used `debugger` the line above it and I could call `model` without any error:

```
   2093          begin
   2094            debugger
=> 2095            model.db.typecast_value(col_schema[:type], value)
   2096          rescue InvalidValue
   2097            raise_on_typecast_failure ? raise : value
   2098          end
   2099        end
(rdb:1) model
Donor
(rdb:1) model.db.typecast_value(col_schema[:type], value)
"ABC"
```

I can also run this code in console successfully, but when running the spec it fails.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ruby solved the problem.